# MapReduce Multiple Reduce Task

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have to take the output of my Mapper and pass it 4 times to my Reducer.

The Reducer is a merger between the data. So after the Mapper, the Reducer merges some data at the first iteration, changes the keys and remerge and the second iteration, and so on...

I try to use `job.setNumReduceTasks(4)` but nothing happens. I have only 1 output and a simple `System.out.println()` placed in my Reducer display only 1 message.

```
Job job = new Job(getConf());


job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
job.setJobName(this.getClass().getName());

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(input));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(output+System.nanoTime()));

job.setMapperClass(KMMapper.class);

job.setReducerClass(KMReducer.class);
job.setNumReduceTasks(4);

job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

----------EDIT ----------

> Also, please update your question with possible i/p adn o/p

I have to implement a new way of clustering data.

The mapper is the clustering algorithm and the output is key/list of points in the cluster.

Each Reducer compares the cluster with the same key and if they are "similar" the reducer merge it. The reducer chooses new keys and the output is newkey/list of points. With a random choice of new keys and a lot of iteration, all the initial clusters will be compared.

Comment: job.setNumReduceTasks defines the how many reducers you will have, not how many time you apply reducing

Comment: and how can I apply the same reducer 4 or 5 times ?

Comment: It is not clear what you need exactly, but have you tried running the same algorithm 4 times (e.g., using a for loop)? You cannot run the reduce phase more than once, because a reducer always runs after a mapper (There is no reduce-only job in MapReduce, even if there can be a map-only job).

Answer (score 1):

> I have to take the output of my Mapper and pass it 4 times to my
>   Reducer.

From the above statement, I could understand that your data have to get filtered/processed 4-times sequentially. To do os, MapReduce provides with `ChainMapper` or `ChainReducer`.

Using `job.setNumReduceTasks(4);` would only help to run 4-reducer task run in parallel, sharing mappers output(called as intermediate data) based on the default key-partition mechanism.

From the other part of you question, custom partitions could be brought in. So, they arrange the key-value pair as key-list of values. Then, based on the required filtering mechanism, merge results in reducer.

Comment: I can read that "The ChainReducer class allows to chain multiple Mapper classes after a Reducer within the Reducer task." but I want the opposite, multiple Reducers for 1 Mapper

Comment: Multiple reducers in MapReduce is just to run parallel jobs out of intermediate data. Its clear and loud that there's no such mechanism of having reducer after reducer(sequential).

Comment: Before i could say yes or no to achiece this, why do you insist on having sequential reducers? while you can have the same with mappers. Also, please update your question with possible i/p adn o/p.

Answer (score 0):

By clustering, do you mean you need to partition the data ?
If that's the case you need to add partitioner logic.( You can provide a range of key, so those keys from mapper goes to a particular reducer.)

Or else you can do one thing, after completion of the first job, apply chaining, so that it goes to the next job, there you have an identity mapper and the reducer logic to perform any business logic.